# Replace array values in string with regex?

Tags: php, regex

Say I have the following array and string:

```
$array  = array('$AA', '$AB', '$AC', '$ZZ');
$string = 'String mentioning $AA and $AB and $CZ and $MARTASS';
```

I want to check $string for matches against $array. Every word in $string that begins with "$" should be checked. In the example, a match is found for $AA and $AB; not for $CZ. The desired output would be:

```
String mentioning {MATCH} and {MATCH} and {NO-MATCH}
```

Is this possible with one regex or is it better to write several lines of PHP? Any input is kindly received :)

Comment: I don't think you can use a single regex to do this

Answer (score 0):

Should be possible with two find-and-replaces, done in this order:

first:

```
\b(($AA)|($AB)|($AC)|($ZZ))\b ---> {MATCH}
```

second:

```
\b$\w+\b ---> {NO-MATCH}
```

I'm not sure this is in PHP syntax, but it shouldn't be too hard to get there. `\b` is a word separator boundary, which I believe is allowed in PHP.

Edit: You might need to escape `$`, not sure as it's grouped.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.  Have a look at the examples in the [preg_replace_callback()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) documentation.  You would use a replace call of the form:

```
function substituteVar($matches) {
    ...
}

...

$newString = preg_replace_callback("/\\$(\w+)/", 'substituteVar', $string);
```

I think I'll leave the content of the `substituteVar()` as an "exercise for the reader".  :-)

Answer (score 0):

This should work...

```
<?php
  $string = 'String mentioning $AA and $AB and $CZ and $MARTASS';
  echo preg_replace_callback("/\\$\S+/",
    create_function('$a','return in_array($a[0],array("\$AA", "\$AB", "\$AC", "\$ZZ")) ? "{MATCH}" : "{NO-MATCH}";'),
    $string
  );
?>
```

Regex matches `$` followed by one or more not spaces (`\S+`) and then checks if the matched string is in the array (included in create function definition so it is in scope, and escaped properly)

Comment: You could also use regex: `/\\$.+?\b/` to match `$` followed by any character un-greedily, followed by a word boundary...

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't bother using a regex here, a simple scan of the string from start to finish, looking for the '$' character and then performing a binary search on the array would be much simpler and faster.